# Adyen Custom Card Secured field not rendering in my Ionic App

Tags: typescript, ionic4, payment-gateway, angular8, adyen

I am not able to render Adyen Payment using Custom Card Secured field in my IONIC4 and Angular8 application

I followed the Adyen documentation each step but still it is not rendering . I have done the modifications in my Index.html,my PaymentsPage.html file

```
1 Index.html file

//Added checkout script and stylesheet 
      <head>
      <script src="https://checkoutshopper-live.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.2.0/adyen.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://checkoutshopper-live.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.2.0/adyen.css" />
      </head>


//Added configuration,checkout mount in my body of Index.html in the 
 bottom

 <body>
<script type="text/javascript">

const configuration = {
rootNode: 'securedfields',
showPayButton: true,
onSubmit: handleOnSubmit,
amount: {             // Optional. Used to display the amount in the Pay 
Button.
        value: 1000,
        currency: 'EUR'
    }
};

 const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(configuration);

  const sf = checkout.create('securedfields', {
  type: 'card',
   groupTypes: ['mc', 'visa', 'amex', 'bcmc', 'maestro'],
   styles: {
    error: {
        color: 'red'
    },
    validated: {
        color: 'green'
    },
    placeholder: {
        color: '#d8d8d8'
    }
},
placeholders: {
    encryptedCardNumber: '9999 9999 9999 9999',
    encryptedExpiryDate: 'mm/yy',
    encryptedSecurityCode: '1234'
},
ariaLabels: {
    lang: 'en-GB',
    encryptedCardNumber: {
        label: 'Credit or debit card number field'
    }
},
// Events
onChange: function() {},
onValid : function() {},
onLoad: function() {},
onConfigSuccess: function() {},
onFieldValid : function() {},
onBrand: function() {},
onError: function() {},
onFocus: function() {},
onBinValue: function(bin) {}
}).mount('#securedfields');

function handleOnSubmit(state, component) {
state.isValid // True or false. Specifies if all the information that the 
shopper provided is valid.
state.data // Provides the data that you need to pass in the `/payments` 
call.
component // Provides the active component instance that called this 
 event.
}

</script>
  </body>
```

2) Changes in my securedpayment.page.html file

```
  <div id="securedfields">
    <label>
        <span>Card number:</span>
        <span data-cse="encryptedCardNumber"></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Expiry date:</span>
        <span data-cse="encryptedExpiryDate"></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>CVV/CVC:</span>
        <span data-cse="encryptedSecurityCode"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I am getting the error message -- unable to mount the component root node not found .

I am expecting i should see Payment page in which when i submit it should submit the data in encrypted way

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you're trying to mount the secure fields onto page before it was rendered. In Angular/Ionic index.html is the wrapper page for your application, it gets parsed, your js in it gets run and only then the content inside is rendered.

I would move the initialisation of your checkout library and secure fields into ngOnInit hook of your payment page.

Alternatively, if you want to have the setup take place in the app component (or whatever your root node component is called) you can put the initialisation and mounting into the ngAfterViewInit hook.

Comment: I managed to resolve that issue but still my fields are not getting rendered. Do you have an experience in rendering through Adyen

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Did you find any fix?